# Copy Xml nodes in other Xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file

```
    <students>
        <student>
        <identity>
            <key>101</key>
        </identity>
        <information>
            <name>abc</name>
            <age>12</age>
            <address>xyz</address>
            .....
        </information>
        <otherinformation>
            <project>
            <name>project1</name>
            <duration>three months</duration>
            </project>
            ....... 
        </otherinformation>
        </student>
        <student>
        <identity>
            <key>102</key>
        </identity>
        <information>
            <name>def</name>
            <age>12</age>
            <address>uvw</address>
            .....
        </information>
        <otherinformation>
            <project>
            <name>project2</name>
            <duration>one month</duration>
            </project>  
        </otherinformation>
        </student>

    </students>
```

So given value of key 101 I would like to copy the information node and `otherinformation` to all the student whatever keys they have. so in this case student with key 102 will have same information and `otherinformation` node as in key 101 after copying.

How can I achieve this.?

Comment: You're looking for XLINQ.

Comment: Can we do this using XLINQ? as the xml file is large somewhere about 30,000 lines so i am looking for multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var students = d.Descendants("student").ToList();
        var student101 = students.First(i => i.Element("identity").Element("key").Value == "101");

        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            student.Descendants("information").Single().ReplaceWith(student101.Descendants("information").Single());
        }

        var x = d.ToString();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx